# SAS - create macros from each row of a dataset

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

```
Target_attr Target_level
ATTR1   CHOCOLATE SBU
ATTR1   CHOCOLATE SBU
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EVERYDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EVERYDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EVERYDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EVERYDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EVERYDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EVERYDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|EASTER
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|HALLOWEEN
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|HOLIDAY
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|VALENTINE
ATTR1|ATTR5 CHOCOLATE SBU|IN/OUT
```

Column's Target_attr values are variables to another dataset and column's Target_level are the values in that columns. 
So what i want to do is create a macro that subsets the dataset like below:

```
row1: if ATTR1="CHOCOLATE SBU" then ...
row2: if ATTR1="CHOCOLATE SBU" then ...
row3: if ATTR1="CHOCOLATE SBU" and ATTR5="EVERYDAY" then ...
```

the other data set is like this:

```
PPGs    ATTR1   ATTR2   ATTR3   ATTR4   ATTR5   ATTR6
A/O BRAND EASTER CH BASKET <=4OZ    CHOCOLATE SBU   A/O MANUFACTURER    A/O FRANCHISE   TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET <=4OZ
A/O BRAND EASTER BASKET <=4OZ   SWEETS SBU  A/O MANUFACTURER    A/O FRANCHISE   TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET <=4OZ
FRANKFORD EASTER BASKET <=4OZ   SWEETS SBU  FRANKFORD   FRANKFORD FR    TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET <=4OZ
A/O BRAND EASTER CH BASKET >4.1OZ   CHOCOLATE SBU   A/O MANUFACTURER    A/O FRANCHISE   TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET >4.1OZ
A/O BRAND EASTER BASKET >4.1OZ  SWEETS SBU  A/O MANUFACTURER    A/O FRANCHISE   TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET >4.1OZ
TIC TAC EVERYDAY BF BOTTLE/POUCH    BREATH FRESHENER    FERRERO TIC TAC FR  INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF BOTTLE/POUCH
TIC TAC EVERYDAY BF CT BOX  CHOCOLATE SBU   FERRERO TIC TAC FR  INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
BREATHSAVERS EVERYDAY BF CT BOX CHOCOLATE SBU   HERSHEY BREATHSAVERS FR INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
ICE BREAKERS FR EVERYDAY BF CT BOX  BREATH FRESHENER    HERSHEY ICE BREAKERS FR INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
MENTOS EVERYDAY BF CT BOX   BREATH FRESHENER    PERFETTI VAN MELLE  MENTOS FR   INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
```

So from first row the subdataset should be

```
PPGs    ATTR1   ATTR2   ATTR3   ATTR4   ATTR5   ATTR6
A/O BRAND EASTER CH BASKET <=4OZ    CHOCOLATE SBU   A/O MANUFACTURER    A/O FRANCHISE   TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET <=4OZ
A/O BRAND EASTER CH BASKET >4.1OZ   CHOCOLATE SBU   A/O MANUFACTURER    A/O FRANCHISE   TAKE HOME   EASTER  BASKET >4.1OZ
TIC TAC EVERYDAY BF CT BOX  CHOCOLATE SBU   FERRERO TIC TAC FR  INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
BREATHSAVERS EVERYDAY BF CT BOX CHOCOLATE SBU   HERSHEY BREATHSAVERS FR INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
```

from 3rd row should be :

```
PPGs    ATTR1   ATTR2   ATTR3   ATTR4   ATTR5   ATTR6
TIC TAC EVERYDAY BF CT BOX  CHOCOLATE SBU   FERRERO TIC TAC FR  INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
BREATHSAVERS EVERYDAY BF CT BOX CHOCOLATE SBU   HERSHEY BREATHSAVERS FR INSTANT CONSUMABLE  EVERYDAY    BF CT BOX
```

I've tried something but it's not worth sharing... 
Can you please help?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please show an example of records from the other dataset, and please show the desired output.  Are you trying to split a dataset into multiple datasets?

Comment: You need to include what you've tried.

Comment: And - this is not the right data structure.  Transpose to vertical/normalized, then a simple join will do what you want far more efficiently.  If the answer is ever "make a macro with a lot of if statements" the question is almost inevitably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot re-engineer this into a join or a format then it is probably easier to generate the desired code using a data step than to use macro variables or macro logic to generate the code.

So if you want to generate

```
if ATTR1="CHOCOLATE SBU" then ...
```

You could use a put statement like:

```
put 'if ' target_attr '=' target_level :$quote. 'then ...';
```

So your whole program would follow this structure.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set METADATA ;
  file code ;
  * generate code ;
  put 'if ' target_attr ....
  ...
run;
data want ;
  set have ;
  %include code /source2 ;
run;
```

One of the advantages of this method is you can review the generated code and make sure the generation logic results in valid code.  It is much easier to review and test pure SAS code than to review code with macro variable references or macro logic.